# Request Tracker Add a custom field

Tags: custom-fields, rt

How do you add a custom field in request Tracker for tickets. I added some through the web gui, but they dont appear on tickets. Could someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have done? Question is not much clear for us to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt repose,

Comment: @NarendraSoni Thanks for your prompt repose

I added a custom field by going to Admin -> Custom Feilds -> Create.

I created something like this: [link](http://postimg.org/image/jqk8f4bh1/). 

However, it does not appear on create new ticket page or any other page. [link](http://postimg.org/image/bfxx0meu3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it's a silly mistake.

I had not "submitted" them by going to Admin > Global > Custom Fields > Tickets. Once selected and submitted, custom fields appear every ticket window.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to assign the Custom Field to tickets in all queues globally. It can be done in `Admin > Global > Custom Fields > Tickets` like you said.

The second way is to assign the Custom Field only to selected queues. This can be done from the CF configuration page (`Admin > Custom Fields > Select`), then select the proper CF and then click on the top right link (`Applies to`) and select some queues.

This answer is valid for the Aileron theme in Request Tracker 4.2.